# Granting SELECT on all tables to a user in Firebird 2.1

Tags: select, firebird, sql-grant, firebird2.1

I've added a user to a Firebird 2.1 instance using *gsec*, but now I wanted to grant SELECT on all tables to this new user. I could find how to grant this permission on specific tables, but not to them all:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE table TO USER user;
```

If I try to use the new user I get the following error on isql:

> no permission for read/select access to TABLE *table*

Is there a way to do that on Firebird 2.1?

Comment: Did you perform the grant in the right database, please describe the exact steps you took, because this should work.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I wonder if he commits those grants and restarts fetching transaction, that perhaps might be cross-transactions thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE tablename VARCHAR(32);
BEGIN
  FOR SELECT rdb$relation_name
  FROM rdb$relations
  WHERE rdb$view_blr IS NULL
  AND (rdb$system_flag IS NULL OR rdb$system_flag = 0)
  INTO :tablename DO
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE STATEMENT ('GRANT SELECT ON TABLE ' || :tablename || ' TO USER TEST');
  END
END
```

Comment: if u check for view sources, then check also for `RDB$EXTERNAL_FILE`. But best would be just to check for `RDB$RELATION_TYPE = 0` /// Next thing would be to enumerate all users too, if we do not want to just grant it all to `PUBLIC` :-)

Comment: Ok, that worked for me. I thought it would have an easy way like on MySQL, but I guess I was wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I could find how to grant this permission on specific tables, but not to them all

You can grant specific privileges to *all users*, already existing and yet to be created. That is made by granting privilege to "PUBLIC" pseudo-user. Or you could grant privileges to some `ROLE`, then grant this `ROLE` to given users, then during database connection specify the option, that the user impersonate this `ROLE` in this session.

However there is no syntax to grant privileges to all generators or all procedures or all views or all tables, etc.

See the `GRANT` statement syntax in documentation.

What you can do though, is creating a simple script (anonymous and volatile aka `EXECUTE BLOCK` or persistent and named as `STORED PROCEDURE`) and that script of yours would be querying *system tables* to list all non-system ( `COALESCE(RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG,0)=0` ) tables (together with views, or tables but not views: check if `RDB$RELATION_TYPE` is 0 or is 0 or 1) and then form a sequence of `GRANT` statements and execute them one by one.

See documentation about `EXECUTE BLOCK` and `FOR SELECT ... INTO ... DO ...` and `EXECUTE STATEMENT` ( or maybe `FOR EXECUTE STATEMENT` also, but I do not think it already was there in FB 2.1. There is unofficial wiki tracking which statements were available since which FB versions, but it is not thorough and may contain errors: http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php ).

- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-security-privs.html#fblangref25-security-privs-grant
- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref-appx04-relations.html
- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-coding.html#fblangref25-psql-execstmt
- https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-execblock.html

Comment: Linking to Russian language sites is not really helpful IMO.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel if there was such a per-version wiki in English.... There is no. Mere checking versions table does not require knowing Russian, though. And if reader got curious, he has www.translate.ru Not a lot, but "better than nothing"